# Sound stutters in Chrome. How do I revert to a previous version of Flash?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, audio, flash, adobe-flash

The sound has started to stutter on last.fm, Grooveshark, and Youtube. How do I revert to an old version of Flash? I tried downloading one of these files, but they were only for Linux:
http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html

Chrome: Version 22.0.1229.94 m

Flash: 11,4,31,110

Windows XP

And which version should I revert to?

Comment: Don't think you can. Flash is incorporated into Chrome directly. You'd have to downgrade your version of Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try any download the [Flash](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/?promoid=JZEFT) stand alone player and use that instead of the PepperFlash you are currently using.

In the `Chrome://plugins` section you will now have 2 entries for flash, disable the PepperFlash entry and try just using the stand alone version.

I had this problem on all three of my home PCs and this seemed to do the trick, might not be the solution to every Flash problem though!

Comment: All it says is `Your Google Chrome browser already includes Adobe® Flash® Player built-in. Google Chrome will automatically update when new versions of Flash Player are available.` If I try to download a different version by saying 'another browser', it redirect to the same page!

Comment: Type `Chrome://plugins` in the search bar at the top and then disable the Flash Player you are currently using, (so no Flash Player is enabled at all) go back to the flash site and then retry the download, then follow the instructions as before and see if you have any luck then!

Comment: That doesn't work. I disabled Flash and downloaded both versions for Internet Explorer and Other Browsers. Still there is only one option in chrome://plugins.

Comment: Had to click "+ Details" first and then there were two Flashes in there. Had to only enable the one that wasn't Pepper/Chrome. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a conflict. The embedded flash in Chrome conflicts with the flash player you've installed in the PC. You have to disable one of these from chrome://plugins/ (write this in the url bar). You can choose what version you want to use.

The problem will go away ;)

Comment: That didn't work. There was only one option for Flash, and that was for Adobe Flash - Version: 11.4.31.110 (Disabled), Shockwave Flash 11.4 r31. There wasn't another Flash option. When I disabled it and went to Youtube, it said "The Adobe Flash Player is required for video playback."

Comment: Here are the extra details: Name: Shockwave Flash
Description: Shockwave Flash 11.4 r31
Version: 11.4.31.110
Location: C:\Documents and Settings\Chloe\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\22.0.1229.94\PepperFlash\pepflashplayer.dll
Type: PPAPI (out-of-process)

Comment: I think it's a problem of the flash incorporated in  chrome. Downgrade the version of the browser..

Comment: How to do that?